# Is it possible to write an SQL query to find data in more than one column based on a third value?

Tags: sql, join, left-join, where-clause

I have a customer database that looks like this:

```
ID  | Name            | Route
------------------------------
001 | John Smith Co.  | 132
002 | John Smith #2   | 201
015 | Casa del Sol    | 132
019 | Partners        | 201
137 | Mary Malones    | 132
```

Some users are type C, and they would be assigned one or more customers by customer number.  Some users are type R and they would be assigned one or more route numbers, which links them to all of the customers in those routes.

```
UserID | Name                 | Type | Link
---------------------------------------------
00001  | Hector Lopez         | C    | 001
00001  | Hector Lopez         | C    | 002
00003  | Tonk Lu              | R    | 132
00309  | Jim Kirk             | C    | 019
```

The effect of this is that Hector's device shows customers 001 and 002, Jim's device shows customer 019, and Tonk's device shows customers 001, 015, and 137. (These would be a chain manager, a customer, and a sales rep, respectively.)

I'm trying to create a query that shows all the customers attached to all users, like so:

```
UserID | Name                 | Type | ID  | Name            
-------------------------------------------------------------
00001  | Hector Lopez         | C    | 001 | John Smith Co.  
00001  | Hector Lopez         | C    | 002 | John Smith #2   
00003  | Tonk Lu              | R    | 001 | John Smith Co.
00003  | Tonk Lu              | R    | 015 | Casa del Sol
00003  | Tonk Lu              | R    | 137 | Mary Malones 
00309  | Jim Kirk             | C    | 019 | Partners
```

But I'm getting hung up on how to handle the R and C logic.  I have two queries, but ideally I'd like to be able to run a single query.

```
Select Users.Username, Users.UserType, Customers.CustomerID, Customers.Name
from Users 
left outer join UserLink on Users.Username = UserLink.Username
left outer join Customers on UserLink.LinkID = Customers.CustomerID
where Users.UserType = 'C'
```

and

```
Select Users.Username, Users.UserType, Customers.CustomerID, Customers.Name
from Users 
left outer join UserLink on Users.Username = UserLink.Username
left outer join Customers on UserLink.LinkID = Customers.Route
where Users.UserType = 'R'
```

Is this possible?  The only information I could find about two columns was matching data on more than one column, like when Year = '2010' and Mfg = 'Ford'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No need to join twice; you can implement the logic with `or`ed join conditions:

```
select
    l.*,
    u.ID,
    u.Name
from Users u
inner join UserLinks l
    on (l.Type = 'C' and l.Link = u.ID)
    or (l.Type = 'R' and l.Link = u.Route)
order by l.UserID, u.ID
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddled](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=224c2e865a4ea20d68191df041c2feda)**:

```
UserID | Name         | Type | Link |  ID | Name          
-----: | :----------- | :--- | ---: | --: | :-------------
     1 | Hector Lopez | C    |    1 |   1 | John Smith Co.
     1 | Hector Lopez | C    |    2 |   2 | John Smith #2 
     3 | Tonk Lu      | R    |  132 |   1 | John Smith Co.
     3 | Tonk Lu      | R    |  132 |  15 | Casa del Sol  
     3 | Tonk Lu      | R    |  132 | 137 | Mary Malones  
   309 | Jim Kirk     | C    |   19 |  19 | Partners
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple clauses in the join. It sounds like you want something like:

```
Select Users.Username, Users.UserType, Customers.CustomerID, Customers.Name
from Users 
left outer join UserLink 
 on Users.Username = UserLink.Username
left outer join Customers 
 on (Users.UserType='C' and UserLink.LinkID = Customers.CustomerID) 
  OR (Users.UserType='R' and UserLink.LinkID = Customers.Route)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first option is to `UNION` those two queries you already have.
You can also use conditionals in the `ON` portion of a `JOIN` clause:

```sql
SELECT Users.Username, Users.UserType, Customers.CustomerID, Customers.Name
FROM Users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserLink
    ON Users.Username = UserLink.Username
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers
    ON UserLink.LinkID = Customers.CustomerID AND Users.UserType = 'C'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Customers
    ON UserLink.LinkID = Customers.Route AND Users.UserType = 'R'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to join the two tables, but use a field determined by the type.  If so, you can use two `left join`s and `coalesce()`:

```
select c.*,
       coalesce(rr.name, rc.name) as name
from customers c left join
     routes rc
     on rc.link = c.id and rc.type = 'C' left join
     routes rr
     on rc.link = c.route and rc.type = 'R';
```

I am not sure what your queries have to do with the question.  The question only refers to two tables.